# Callback setting variable later than the function triggers

Tags: javascript, callback, socket.io

```
handler: function(item){
    var info;
    Database.getInfo(item, function(data){ 
        if(data)
            info = data.information
    });
    // Socket.io join handler
    socket['user'].join(info)
}
```

Now I try to get the `info` inside the `Database.getInfo` to send it with the socket.

Whenever I use `socket['user'].join(info)` inside the callback of `Database.getInfo` I get the `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'join'`.

And outside, as you can guess I get a empty var, because the callback sets the variable after the `join()` is called..

What can i do to get the `info` from the `Database.getInfo` to use it mysend the socket?

Comment: When you say method error - what is the error message like? Care to share?

Comment: From `socket.io` documentation I can see there is a `join` API which is usually used by calling `socket.join(...)` Your code doesn't look like the usual way of using `.join`. What really is `socket`? Care to reveal more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

The database callback is async.  It is called sometime later while the rest of your `handler` function continues to run.  You can only use the `data` result inside the callback itself because that's the only place you know the timing for when the info is actually available.

```
handler: function(item){
    Database.getInfo(item, function(data){ 
        if(data) {
            let info = data.information
            // Socket.io join handler
            socket['user'].join(info);
        }
    });
    // any code placed here runs BEFORE the getInfo() callback runs
}
```

Comment: Whenever i use it inside the calback I get the error that join has no method

Comment: @J.Doe - If you want help with that error, you will have to add to your question exactly what code you tried and the EXACT error message you got.  "join has no method" is not likely what the error message for this code says.  It might say something about `.join` being `undefined`.  If that's the case, then the problem is probably with `socket['user']` which is code you don't show us.

Comment: @J.Doe - Then that's some other problem.  Apparently, you haven't yet set `socket` or `socket['user']` yet when you are trying to use it.  There is nothing disclosed in your question that allows us to help with that.  The bit about when you can use data in an async callback is Asynchronous Javascript basics 101.  You HAVE to do it this way.  That will cause you to have to also fix your other problem with `socket['user']`.